# OS X advanced wireless adapter configuration

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking

Windows drivers typically offer advanced configuration options for wireless adapters. For example, you can specify a frequency, network standard, or adjust roaming aggressiveness.

Unfortunately, Network Preferences does not offer any of these adjustments. Is there a way to modify these "advanced" settings via GUI or command prompt, specifically with OS X 10.6 and later?